# Generate random numbers in solidity

Tags: node.js, blockchain, solidity

I am trying to build a simple game which will generate 3 random numbers from 1 to 10 in a row. If there are 3 same numbers in a row i should send x amount of ether as reward to the user.

I am wondering how to generete theese numbers and i came up with two solutions which are not very good for my opition.

1.Make a function in the conctract to generate random numbers

2.Generate random numbers from backend like Nodejs

In my opition, if i use the first option gas fees will be much expensive.
The second options seems fine to me, but how to protect the function which generates random numbers.The idea is that this function generates random numbers and base on theese numbersthe user wins prizes.My question is how to protect this function so it can't be manipulated by other people.

If you have better ideas how to generated thease numbers let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I have no much experiance with solidity but for generating random numbers in solidity i have used chainlink VRF.

*Chainlink VRF (Verifiable Random Function) is a provably fair and verifiable random number generator (RNG) that enables smart contracts to access random values without compromising security or usability*

Below is the VRF documentation.

https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf/v2/subscription/examples/get-a-random-number/

Comment: This is the only correct answer now. To add to this, it's only expensive on the Ethereum mainnet with v1 Chainlink VRF. Fantom and Avalanche have instant finality, and Polygon is a lot cheaper. After the botched merge, Ethereum is pretty broken for many things. Devs should explore the multichain powers of this VRF service.